# Magento - Access Session Variable within custom module

Tags: magento, session, module

On my site i have several pages which set a core session variable as so:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setSellYourArtCheck(1);
```

If i want to access this anywhere i can successfully do:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getSellYourArtCheck();
```

But i now need to access this session variable in my custom module but it is showing as empty/null when i try and access it as above.

My Observer.php code for my module:

```
<?php
class Custom_RegisterArtist_Model_Observer
{
    public function registerArtist(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        // other code....

        $is_artist = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getSellYourArtCheck();
        if($is_artist == 1)
        {
            $customer->setData('group_id', 4);
        }

        // other code....
     }
}
```

My `$is_artist` variable is always empty/null within my module but is fine on any of my pages

Comment: Are you sure the session variable has been set before the event/observer is fired.

Comment: Yes it is definitely set beforehand. The event that my module is called on is the customer_save_before

Comment: are they set in the same thread ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your observer is called after your load the page, so the value is actually not set.

This is the correct way of setting session variables (as you wrote)

```
Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->setMySessionVariable("test"); 

$myValue  =  Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->getMySessionVariable();

echo $myValue;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but sorry i don't understand how this is meant to solve?

Comment: on which action is your observer triggered?